# What is the best way to store settings in C# PCL

Tags: c#, storage, portable-class-library, application-settings

I am a developer of cross-platform C# application which currently targets Windows Store and Xamarin environments. I have a shared portable class library (PCL) referenced by all aplications, where i define core application logics and algorithms, including storage, networking, database and settings.

What i need is a smarter way of storing settings. I don't want to use any key-value methods or XML files, as these methods outdated completely, then this is easily possible in C#:

```
[SettingsNode("app_settings")]
class AppSettings
{
    public double SomeNumber;
    public object SomeSerializable;

    public byte[] SomeBytes;

    [SettingsNode("custom_setting_name")]//just specifying XML/etc node name with SettingsNode attribute
    public string SomeKey;
}

class x
{
    void y()
    {
        AppSettings superSettingsSolution = Engine.LoadEntry<AppSettings>("test.xml");
        superSettingsSolution.SomeBytes = new byte[10];
        superSettingsSolution.SomeNumber = 4.6d;
        superSettingsSolution.SomeSerializable = new object();//[Serializable] class
        Engine.SaveEntry<AppSettings>("test.xml", superSettingsSolution);
    }
}
```

I going to use PCLStorage package for cross-platform storage, so i am not referencing System.Windows.Storage in my code and i don't want to.

My question: is there anything close to my code example library/project/package  for C#'s PCL? I am sorry if i am asking something trivial, but i am not experinced 'portable'/windows8 programmer yet.

Comment: why do you say : "key-value methods or XML files, as these methods outdated completely"?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe because it use strings as key names we want to retrieve, and they are always the same, but looking for string-named parameter each time code requests named value cause enumerating all available keys and comparing them (+time), while we can use 'native' protperties and fields of classes. Also, the names will not change and there is no need to name they as strings in code (in most cases).

Comment: You can use classic XmlSerializer and [XmlElement], [XmlAttribute] .. etc. attributes to shape xml input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using PCLStorage;
    using System.IO;

    public virtual async Task<T> LoadSettings<T>(IFile file = null)
        where T : IApplicationSettings
    {
        // File
        if (file == null)
            file = DefaultSettingsFile;

        // Open file
        using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xmls.Deserialize(fileStream);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task SaveSettings(object settings, IFile file = null)
    {
        // File
        if (file == null)
            file = DefaultSettingsFile;

        // Open file
        using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite))
        {
            var xmls = new XmlSerializer(settings.GetType());
            xmls.Serialize(fileStream, settings);
        }
    }
```